# SQL Change another row for id based off of value in a different row

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and am trying to create a command that would do the following:

if _stripe_customer_id = cus_1 then for that post_ID, set _requires_manual_renewal = true and set _payment_method to BLANK and set _payment_method_title to BLANK.

I know what I need to but am not familiar with the commands to make it happen.

Here is an example of my table (wp_postmeta)

```
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|meta_id|post_id|        meta_key         | meta_value |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   1   | 11221 |   _stripe_customer_id   |   cus_1    |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   2   | 11221 |_requires_manual_renewal |   false    |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   3   | 11221 |     _payment_method     |   stripe   |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   4   | 11221 |  _payment_method_title  |   stripe   |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   5   | 11223 |   _stripe_customer_id   |   cus_1    |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   6   | 11223 |_requires_manual_renewal |   false    |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   7   | 11223 |     _payment_method     |   stripe   |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   8   | 11223 |  _payment_method_title  |   stripe   |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   9   | 11225 |   _stripe_customer_id   |            |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   10  | 11225 |_requires_manual_renewal |   true     |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   11  | 11225 |     _payment_method     |            |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
|   12  | 11225 |  _payment_method_title  |            |
+-------+-------+-------------------------+------------+
```

Thanks for any help or direction that you provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that for BLANK you mean null

```
update my_table a 
inner join  (
  select post_id
  from my_table 
  where meta_value = 'cus_1'
  and meta_key  ='_stripe_customer_id '
) t1 on t1.post_id = a.post_id
 and meta_key in ('_payment_method', ' _payment_method_title')
 set meta_value  = NULL
```

Otherwise if you mean  string empty for BLANK then

```
update my_table a 
inner join  (
  select post_id
  from my_table 
  where meta_value = 'cus_1'
  and meta_key  ='_stripe_customer_id '
) t1 on t1.post_id = a.post_id
 and meta_key in ('_payment_method', ' _payment_method_title')
 set meta_value  = ''
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the second one (for the empty string) and ran it twice to modify the _requires_manual_renewal = "true" lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 SQL statements

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET  'meta_value' = true
WHERE  meta_key ='_requires_manual_renewal'
   AND post_id IN
        (
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key ='_stripe_customer_id' 
          AND meta_value='cus_1'
        )
;       

UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET  'meta_value' = ''
WHERE  meta_key IN ('_payment_method', '_payment_method_title')
   AND post_id IN
        (
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_postmeta 
        WHERE meta_key ='_stripe_customer_id' 
          AND meta_value='cus_1'
        )           
;
```